# ReplayKit - keeping reference to RPPreviewViewController in ObjectiveC

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, garbage-collection, replaykit

I have a problem with keeping a reference to a RPPreviewViewController in ReplayKit with ObjectiveC and I'm wondering what am I doing wrong.

The .h file:

```
@interface ReplayKitHelper : NSObject <RPPreviewViewControllerDelegate, RPScreenRecorderDelegate>

-(void)startRecording;
-(void)stopRecording;
-(void)previewRecording;

@property(strong) RPPreviewViewController* previewViewControllerRef;

@end
```

The .mm file:

```
@implementation ReplayKitHelper

@synthesize previewViewControllerRef;

-(void)startRecording
{
    RPScreenRecorder* recorder = RPScreenRecorder.sharedRecorder;

    recorder.delegate = self;

    [recorder startRecordingWithMicrophoneEnabled : true handler : ^ (NSError *error)
    {
    }];
}

-(void)stopRecording
{
    RPScreenRecorder* recorder = RPScreenRecorder.sharedRecorder;

    [recorder stopRecordingWithHandler : ^ (RPPreviewViewController * previewViewController, NSError * error)
    {
        if (error == nil)
        {
            if (previewViewController != nil)
            {
                previewViewControllerRef = previewViewController;
            }
        }
    }];
}

-(void)previewRecording
{
    if (previewViewControllerRef != nil)
    {
        previewViewControllerRef.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
        previewViewControllerRef.previewControllerDelegate = self;
        [[IOSAppDelegate GetDelegate].IOSController presentViewController : previewViewControllerRef animated : YES completion : nil];
        // IOSController is my main UIViewController
    }
}
@end
```

During the runtime I launch methods startRecording, stopRecording and previewRecording, in that order. Everything is going fine, until previewRecording, where it looks like the previewViewControllerRef is no longer valid (it's not nil, but it crashes when I'm trying to refer to it).

When I try to run [self previewRecording] inside the stopRecordingWithHandler block, after I pass the reference - everything works fine.

It looks like the previewViewController from the handler is released right after app leaves the block.

Most of the examples are written in Swift, unfortunatelly I'm condemned to ObjectiveC. In Swift examples the reference to previeViewController is just passed to the variable, but in ObjectiveC it seems to not working.

Do You have any ideas what's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you are using ARC, if so there is no need to synthesize properties anymore.

Change your RPPreviewViewController in the Interface file to:

@property (nonatomic, strong) RPPreviewViewController *RPPreviewViewController;

Drop the @synthesize.

then in the stopRecording handler you can keep a reference to the available RPPreviewViewController like so:

```
- (void)stopScreenRecording {
RPScreenRecorder *sharedRecorder = RPScreenRecorder.sharedRecorder;
[sharedRecorder stopRecordingWithHandler:^(RPPreviewViewController *previewViewController, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"stopScreenRecording: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }

    if (previewViewController) {
        self.previewViewController = previewViewController;
    }
}];
}
```

In my experience ReplayKit is still buggy and there isn't a lot of documentation about it yet.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it worked like a charm! Atomic and no synthesizing did a trick. Also, I've discovered that on iOS9 you have to run preview always on the main thread.